# WCF broken when referencing Tasks.Dataflow

Tags: c#, wcf

I have two applications and I want to communicate between them using WCF using a Named Pipe. And it's broken.

The error is either a`EndpointNotFoundException` by the client if you start the ServiceHost in a separate Thread or a Server-side `FaultException` followed by a `AddressAlreadyInUseException` by the client if you open the host in the main thread (which btw. does not work regardless of the bug).

The Exceptions were traced using a modified App.config as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/configuring-tracing).

- Both projects are using .NET Framework 4.7.1
- The Server-side application is referencing System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow
- The client side is not referencing anything worth noting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fault lies in the referenced System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow library and the way I consume WCF. It introduces a bunch of annoying references, that are not really necessary and alters the app.config without telling the user.

It adds a list of `assemblyBinding`-Tags into the result in the output directory, even if the user does not desire to do so. One of them looks like this:

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

This rebind is the key. I used to start the WCF-Process, wait some time with `Thread.Sleep` (500ms-ish) and then try to connect the client. Without the rebind, this works just fine. With it though it doesn't, because 500ms is too low now. Ramping that up to 1s works just fine again.

In Summary: the rebind causes a minor overhead in WCF that threw my timing off.